# Elasticsearch Vs Database Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, elasticsearch

How i can compare field between field on elasticsearch and field on database oracle

example like on image :

[image: 1]

like try on manual search one by one, try to matched field to field

Comment: not sure what you want to achieve. My understanding is that you want to verify that a document already indexed in Elasticsearch matches field by field to a record persisted in Oracle. And you want to run this verification for a large number of documents in Elasticsearch. Is that correct?

Comment: yeah something like that..
because im tired search and compare one by one

Comment: do you have a field you can use as unique identifier for both documents and records? if so, you can write a script to fetch all records from oracle -> search in elasticsearch -> compare (or the other way around)